# Why do my photos on LG G6 seem overly compressed?

Tags: photos, lg, lg-g6

I've just come back from a nice hiking trip where I took lots of photos that looked good on the LG G6 screen.

[image]

But looking at them closely, there is very little detail - they've been heavily smoothed.

Here are those rocks in the midground:

[image]

I have the image quality settings at 4:3 (13MP) and this particular image is 4.4MB (original [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rm2fyxir4bo6kir/20171122_205944_HDR_orig.jpg?dl=0)).

Is this normal? Is there anything I can do about it?

(I'm using Google Photos, but the screenshots and original image above come from exporting directly out of Gallery, to email.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. LG camera software does it.

You can fix it with [Google Camera ported to LG G6](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g6/how-to/google-camera-hdr-ported-g6-t3655374). It may lack some functions compared to LG camera app.